# Не выравнивается по центру блок div

Tags: html, css

Есть вот такой код

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12" style="text-align: center;">
            <img src="/images/usual_people.png"/>

            <br /><br />

            <div style="border:2px solid #c5c6c6; padding:10px; border-radius:20px; width:200px;">
            duddeniska
            </div>
        </div>
```

Почему блок с надписью не выравнивается по центру?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дайте ему margin: 0px auto; если хотите блочным оставить, или инлайн-блок

Comment: Иногда, вполне не плохо спасает `<div align="center"> </div>`

Answer (score 0):

1. `margin: 0 auto;` для div
2. Для выравнивания содержимого по центру в бутстрапе есть класс, позволяющий не писать `style="text-align:center;"` - `text-center`

   ```
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 text-center">
       <img src="/images/usual_people.png"/>
       <br /><br />
       <div style="
           border:2px solid #c5c6c6;
           padding:10px;
           border-radius:20px;
           width:200px;
           margin: 0 auto;
       ">
           duddeniska
       </div>
   </div>
   ```